# How to fetch lines between two strings using shell script?

Tags: shell-scripting

How to fetch lines between two strings using shell script?
For example I am having a file called  file_text.txt as below.

```
MEDIUMINT
CREATE ( 
MAXVALUE 
MEDIUMBLOB
MEDIUMINT
MEDIUMTEXT
MIDDLEINT );
MINUTE_SECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
CREATE (
MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
MOD );
MODIFIES
MEDIUMINT
CREATE (
NATURAL
NOT
NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG
NULL );
NUMERIC
ON
OPTIMIZE
```

I want to grep all lines between CREATE and  ; from the file. Including the CREATE and ;string.

Comment: are ; characters followed by new line? do you want whole lines or just the part with CREATE..; ?

Comment: all line in between  CREATE..; including the line having CREATE and ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
sed '/^CREATE/,/);$/!d;s/^CREATE (//;s/);$//' file_text.txt
```

will output:

```
MAXVALUE 
MEDIUMBLOB
MEDIUMINT
MEDIUMTEXT
MIDDLEINT 

MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
MOD 

NATURAL
NOT
NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG
NULL
```

Or in case you need `CREATE (` and `);` just do

```
sed '/^CREATE/,/);$/!d' file_text.txt
```

It will do smth like that:

```
CREATE ( 
MAXVALUE 
MEDIUMBLOB
MEDIUMINT
MEDIUMTEXT
MIDDLEINT );
CREATE (
MINUTE_MICROSECOND
MINUTE_SECOND
MOD );
CREATE (
NATURAL
NOT
NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG
NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo "...youriput..." | tr -d "\n" | tr ';' '\n' | grep CREATE | sed "s/.*CREATE\(.*\)/CREATE\1;/"
```